# Able to copy FROM tftp server, but unable to WRITE in tftp server

Tags: copy, tftp

i been for a month trying to get into UBUNTU and linux systems, which i think is great, im having a good experience. But the thing is i always get stuck into something... i always been a windows guy and sometimes little things just kill me...

One of the little things is that i cant write from a cisco device into my TFTP server that i got running on my ubuntu... BUT i do can get access to the files in my ubuntu server and copy them into my cisco devices that i got running my network.

I run this three commands after installing that i believe it gave permissions to write in the tftp folder, but nothing happens...

```
$ sudo mkdir /tftpboot
$ sudo chmod -R 777 /tftpboot
$ sudo chown -R nobody /tftpboot
```

I followed this guide to install tftp server

https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/set-up-a-tftp-server-on-ubuntu-server/

thanks to all for your attention and sorry for my weird English

Comment: Knowing which linked procedure you "followed" tells us nothing about what you actually DID, nor about any error/informative messages you saw. Look at the output of `journalctl  /usr/sbin/in.tftpd`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [`man tftpd`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/atftpd.8.html):

> The use of tftp(1) does not require an account or password on the remote system.  Due to the lack of authentication information, tftpd will allow only publicly readable files to be accessed. Files may be written only if they already exist and are publicly writable.

`tftpd` will not create files. It will only allow overwriting.

Comment: Thanks !!! i got it !!! took me a while to understand that part, thanks a lot !!!